# async.eachSeries not working as expected

Tags: node.js, debugging, asynchronous, node-inspector

I'm having a hard time with async.eachSeries. I've created a peace of code to illustrate.

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
function doJob(callback){
    debugger; //#1
    async.eachSeries(arr, function(task, cb){
        console.log('Starting checking function');
        debugger; //#2
        if(task%2 === 0){
            debugger; //#3
            console.log('Task even: ' + task);

            r.exists("somekty", function(err ,result){
                if(err || result){
                    debugger; //#4
                    cb(null);
                }else{
                    debugger; //#5
                    cb(null);
                }
            });
        }else{
            debugger;//#6
            console.log('Task odd: ' + task);
                cb(null);
        }
        debugger;//#7
    }, function(err){
        callback()
    });
}

setTimeout(function(){
    doJob(function(){
        console.log('All done!');
    })
}, 1000)
```

When I execute the code above, the expected result shoud be(for me):
Hit: #1

1 iteration: #2 - #6

2 iteration: #2 - #3 - #7 - #4||#5

3 iteration: ....
...

And keep going.... but what happens is when it goes for the first time inside the "if" that has a async function(redis) it just goes to #7 and never stops at #4 or #5 and finishes the code. Why?

I'm using iron-node for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

> but what happens is when it goes for the first time
>   inside the "if" that has a async function(redis) it just goes to #7
>   and never stops at #4 or #5 and finishes the code. Why?

That's how async code works.  If `r.exists()` is async, then calling it STARTS the operation and then the rest of your code continues to execute.  async operations do not block until complete.  Calling them just starts the operation and then the rest of your code continues to execute.

So, when `task%2 === 0`, then you would go into that branch of your code.  It would then call `r.exists(...)`.  That will initiate that async operation and then the lines of your code after that will continue to run.

The next thing that executes in your code is `debugger;//#7` so that will trigger.

At that point `async.eachSeries()` will come into play and will not execute the next iteration of your loop until somebody calls `cb(null)`, which in your code will happen when `r.exists()` finishes and calls its callback.

When `task%2 === 0`, you should see this sequence:

```
#2, #3, #7, #4|#5
```

which is apparently what you observe.

---

FYI, it can sometimes be confusing to understand the real timing of your code when using lots of debugger breakpoints because stopping at the breakpoint itself influences the timing of various operations (it gives native code async operations a chance to run and complete while sitting at the breakpoint).  When understanding pure timing of asynchronous operations, it is usually better to just use `console.log()` statements to output enough info to document the real sequence of things.

Comment: Yes, I agree with everything you said and also understand. The problem is that I would expect it to be in serie and it is not what happen. When the scripts get into the "r.exists" for the first time it goes to #7 (as expected) and should wait until "r.exists" finishes and then activate debugger #4 or #5. But what happens is after it hits #7, the code magically finishes without stopping at #4 or #5.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about this async debugging "problem".

Comment: @HaroldFinch - `async.eachSeries()` itself is asynchronous.  So calling it, just initiates the operation.  The lines of code after it will execute as soon as the first iteration of the loop is done and while that iteration is waiting for an async operation.  This is asynchronous programming in Javascript.  If you want some code to execute AFTER the `async.eachSeries()` operation is completely done, then you put that code in the final callback for `async.eachSeries()`.  That's what that callback is for.